# Would this be eligible on code golf (to know before writing a contest in Sandbox)?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

A while ago I ended up on a StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825821/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-gawk-and?answertab=votes#tab-top) which I believe could fit under [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) category as it's all about killing the idea a C program could beat anything else in speed (here the main competitor is `mawk` for text processing with regexes).

As there's already been a wide meta-effect on this question on SO, I'm unsure it would be on-topic there or not, so before writing a challenge about it I have two questions:

1. Would it be on-topic (and with which tag ?)
2. Is the test system in place (github+travis) valid to classify answers

Side Note: Would the test system be of some interest for other challenges ?

P.S: Tell me if I should copy here parts of the existing SO and Meta-SO questions to ease the understanding (but the subject is quite vast now and I'm afraid making this one too long by overquoting)

Comment: A King of the Hill is a game or competitive challenge with interaction between competitors (like Checkers or Tank Wars). If you're going for "what's fastest", there is a [fastest-code tag](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) that sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Editing, after reading too much around I used the wrong tag ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sandbox it and see

Go ahead and write up a sandbox post. We'll give you critique on what is unclear, what should be changed, etc. It's much easier to answer "is this a good challenge" when looking at a fleshed-out sandbox post than a short description here. If it works, great! If not, oh well, you've (hopefully) learned something for the future.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

We like [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) problems.

In the future, if you want to identify whether a problem is feasible, we have a [friendly chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) that would love to critique your problem (as posting that on meta seems kind of overkill IMO).

Edit:  I'm not indicating that your post here is off-topic or that we have rules against issues that are "too small", just that I would personally ask in chat.

Comment: Aww, used to meta SO where questions out of scope for main are the best place to go.